# Using Moment.js in Ember Controller inside a computed function using data-table columns

Tags: date, ember.js, datatable, momentjs, ember-cli

I was wondering if it is possible to apply a Date format of `MM-DD-YYYY`
to the `valuePath` of a Data-Table Column array within a controller for an Ember route.

My `controller.js`:

```
columns: computed(function() {
    return A([{
            valuePath: 'firstName',
            label: get(this, 'i18n').t('page.firstName'),
            cellClassNames: 'cell-valign-middle',
            sortable: true,
        }, {
            valuePath: "lastName",
            label: get(this, 'i18n').t('page.lastName'),
            cellClassNames: 'cell-valign-middle',
            sortable: true,
        }, {
            valuePath: "dateOfBirth",
            label: get(this, 'i18n').t('page.dateOfBirth'),
            cellClassNames: 'cell-valign-middle',
            sortable: false,
        },
    ]);
}),
```

`template.hbs`

```
{{#data-table 
  columns=columns 
  models=model 
  sort=sort 
  isLoading=isLoadingModels 
  responsive=true}}
{{/data-table}}
```

My goal is to turn `valuePath` for `dateOfBirth` to a Date format of `MMDDYYYY` using `moment.js`.

I have tried `moment("dateOfBirth").format("MMDDYYYY")` without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, there would be a 'format' attribute in the configuration of each column, so you can define a format method.

Another method would be since the table will query the model for the attribute 'valuePath', you can have a computed directly in the model to return the formatted date.

*models/user.js*

```
 formatted: Ember.computed('dateOfBirth', function () {
    const dateOfBirth = this.get('dateOfBirth');
    return moment(dateOfBirth).format('MMDDYYYY')
  })
```

p.d.: I'm not sure which plugin for tables you are using. If you could post it here I can dig more into the documentation.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much, now I can leverage this to create more computed variables that requir something similar to this approach. Really appreciate the quick help.